# How to set Physics definition programmatically in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I can set physics definition at GameScene.sks file:

[image: GameScene.sks]

But how can I change these physics definition parameters (body type, allows rotation, category mask,...) in code programmatically ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is real simple,  just create a new instance of SKPhysicsBody with whatever type you want, set the properties the way you want it, and then assign a node.

See https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skphysicsbody for more details.

```
let physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(....type)
physicsBody.(someSetting1)
physicsBody.(someSetting2)
physicsBody.(someSetting3)
node.physicsBody = physicsBody
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Knight0fDragon